# How to pass filename while writing to a file in Python

Tags: python

I am currently using python script to copy files from SFTP server and move them to my local machine. Also I am trying to send a response to the server that I am copying these files. I would like to know how to pass the file name in the notification text.

This is the current code:

```
location_FileImporter = "C:\\*\\*\\*\\*"
file_cache = location_FileImporter + "\\cache"
file_in = location_FileImporter + "\\in\\"
file_out = location_FileImporter + "\\out"
file_error = location_FileImporter + "\\error\\" + party + "_error.txt"
file_notification = location_FileImporter + "\\" + party + "_notification.txt"

#Puts notification file on the FTP server, notifying the 3rd party the file has been picked up.
print("\n(5/5) Notifying " + party + " how many files have been copied from the " + server + ".")
checkConnection()
try:
    notificationFile = open(file_notification, 'w') #Trying to create a new file or open one.
    notificationFile.write(str(nfiles_used) + " out of " + str(nfiles_copied) + " used.") #Append the error message to the file.
    if (nfiles_used != nfiles_copied):
        notificationFile.write("Only files with the \'.csv\' extension have been used.")
    notificationFile.close() #Close the file.
except:
    createErrorMessage(error_file_create_notification)
try:
    ftp.storlines("STOR " + str(time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))) + " - notification.txt", open(file_notification, 'rb'))
    print("--> Successfully created the \'notification.txt\' file on the " + party + " " + server + ".")
    os.remove(file_notification)
except:
    createErrorMessage(error_file_set_notification)
print("--------------------------------------------------------")
```

In the above code I am trying to copy the files from SFTP to cache and then copying them to the input folder.

Comment: What is wrong with the code so far?

Comment: `notification text` is a vague term. Define your problem more clearly.

Comment: 2 tips you could use now: use context manager `with` when you handle files, limit your lines length to 80

Comment: I am trying to copy file from third party SFTP server and put back a response saying that I have copied these files. The code which I have mentioned above shows how I am creating a response (notification.txt) and writing contents to it. Here I would like to include the file name which I copied. How do i do that?